# Budgies Beak Injury

Tags: parrots

I have kept budgies for over a year. Budgies fight often. One baby budgie was hurt badly by another adult budgie. His beak was badly hurt and completely torn from one side. I have taken him to a vet and got the wound cleaned up. My question is whether the beak will grow back after some time? The vet told me its not scientifically proven.

Comment: was there any blood coming from the injured part of the beak,if the blood suply to a part of the beak is cut off it will not grow in that area.

Comment: Welcome User17948! Are you able to post photos of the injury?

Comment: The wound is now dried. There was not a lot of blood flow. He is healthy now and the parents are feeding him. His upper beak which was hurt, had dropped after the wound dried up. Now he don,t have an upper beak but he survived. I hope it grows back. Thanks for the concern